# Impact analysis on IBM i through Aldon

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am making changes to a "reference file" which is an SQL table by adding a new field to it.
The only way this file should be used is by referring to it when writing the DDS or DDL of other tables/files.

Hence I expect no impact(run time errors in programs etc.) due to a change in this file. However, when I take option 41 against this file (Work with dependant objects), I see a huge list of objects and I can confirm that the file is not used by these programs. It is even displaying binder language source files as dependant.

So I am starting to wonder what actually is being displayed by Aldon and how to confirm that this file is not used directly in any programs ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off asking Aldon...

But if I recall correctly, Aldon's dependency information is tracked at the object level.  Since your reference file is used to define fields in other files and those other files are used in programs, it's not surprising to see programs shown as a dependency.

I thought there was a way to limit the recursiveness of the info displayed.  But a glance through my old LM(i) 8.2 manual suggests that the recursion is done manually.

> To display and act upon dependent objects recursively You can use
> LM(i) to display and act upon objects that are dependent on dependent
> objects, and objects that are in turn dependent on those dependent
> objects.
>
> 1. Display dependent objects for an object that is defined to LM(i) on the Act Upon Dependent Objects panel as described in “To access the
>    Act upon Dependent Objects panel,” starting on page UG 2-44.
> 2. At the Act upon Dependent Objects panel, by the dependent object for which you want to display dependent objects, type 41 or 42 (Act
>    upon dependent objects) and press ENTER.
>
> Note Repeat step 2 to display dependent objects at deeper levels of recursion.